# error in console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPosition' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, xmlhttprequest

I need help, i try to made a motor search with the GMap API v3. I test the code with an array to markers, but when i try to test with markers from my mysql db in some point of the test the app fail, no have a patron to fail when a move the markeruser. this is the code with the array for markers.

```
<head>   <meta charset="utf-8">   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>   <style>
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      height: 90%;
      width: 90%;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px
    }   </style>   </head> <div class='titular'> (Motor Busqueda)</div> <body onload="init()">
        <div id="map"></div>



  <script>
    var map,   searchArea,   searchAreaMarker,   searchAreaRadius = 1000, // metres   startLat = 40.782827,   startLng = -73.966167;

function init() {   var startLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(startLat, startLng);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: startLatLng,
    zoom: 15   });

  searchArea = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.2,
    map: map,
    center: startLatLng,
    radius: searchAreaRadius   });

  searchAreaMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: startLatLng,
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    title: 'searchAreaMarker'   });

  var randomMarkers = [{
    title: 'Marker 1',
    latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(40.770088, -73.971146)   }, {
    title: 'Marker 2',
    latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(40.782048, -73.972691)   }, {
    title: 'Marker 3',
    latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(40.769048, -73.987797)   }, {
    title: 'Marker 4',
    latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(40.773858, -73.956211)   }, {
    title: 'Marker 5',
    latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(40.800372, -73.952091)   }, {
    title: 'Marker 6',
    latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(40.804661, -73.939388)   }];

  for (var i = 0; i < randomMarkers.length; i++) {
    randomMarkers[i].marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: randomMarkers[i].latLng,
      map: map,
      title: randomMarkers[i].title
    });   }

  google.maps.event.addListener(searchAreaMarker, 'dragend', function(e) {
    startLatLng = e.latLng;

    searchArea.setOptions({
      center: startLatLng
    });

    map.panTo(searchAreaMarker.getPosition());

    // find markers in area
    for (var i = 0; i < randomMarkers.length; i++) {


      // ---------- Here comes the error: 
      // TypeError: e is undefined
      if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(randomMarkers[i].marker.getPosition(), searchArea.getCenter()) <= searchArea.getRadius()) {
          randomMarkers[i].marker.setMap(map); } else {
    randomMarkers[i].marker.setMap(null);
      }
    }   }); }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

  </script>    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBLUQx80thnYElakuZ6sIFt4vWYR6kE4Ss&callback=" async defer></script> </body> </html>
```

and this other with markers from my db:

```
function load() {
  var markers = [];
  var circle = null;
  var startLatLng;
  var point;
    //----------------Declaracion de variable latlng--------------------
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(4.678402871749015,-74.09417855941774); 
    //----------------Inicializar Mapa--------------------------
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: latlng,
      zoom: 14,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });




    //----------------Declaracion variable infowindow--------------------
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    //----------------Marcadores de BD--------------------
    downloadUrl("php/markers.php", function(data) {
      var xml = data.responseXML;
      markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
        point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var icon = 'gal/marker.png';
        var markers[i].marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: point,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          icon: icon,
          id: id
        }); // End Marker
      } // End for



      //-----------Marcador Usuario-------------------
    var markeruser = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title:"Esto es un marcador",
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        }); 
    //-----------Circulo de area---------------------
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map,
            radius: Math.sqrt(1000) * 15
    });
    //-----------Enlazar marcador y circle--------------
    circle.bindTo('center', markeruser, 'position');



    //-----------------Search-----------------------------
     google.maps.event.addListener(markeruser, 'draggend', function(e) {
        startLatLng = e.latLng;

        circle.setOptions({
          center: startLatLng
        });
        map.panTo(markeruser.getPosition());

        // find markers in area
        searchWithinMarker();
                });//End function




    });// End dowload

        document.getElementById('show-listings').addEventListener('click', showListings);
        document.getElementById('hide-listings').addEventListener('click', hideListings);







} // End Load Map





function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
    new XMLHttpRequest;
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
}

function searchWithinMarker(){

        // find markers in area
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

          if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markers[i].marker.getPosition(), circle.getCenter()) <= circle.getRadius()) {
              markers[i].marker.setMap(map);
              } else {
                  markers[i].marker.setMap(null);
                    }//End If
                  }//End For

}
function showListings() {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  // Extend the boundaries of the map for each marker and display the marker
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].marker.setMap(map);
    bounds.extend(markers[i].marker.position);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
// This function will loop through the listings and hide them all.
function hideListings() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].marker.setMap(null);
  }
}



function doNothing() {}
```

the html is:

```
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBLUQx80thnYElakuZ6sIFt4vWYR6kE4Ss&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
</head>
<div class='titular'>Coffee Search (Motor Busqueda)</div>
<body onload="initMap()">

        <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

css is:

```
body {
    margin-top:3%;
    margin-left:5%;
    background: #cccccc;
}
#info {
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 350px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #666666;
    border: solid 1px #666666;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 3px;

}
#enviar {
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000;
    margin: 10px 60px;
    padding:3px 10px 3px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
#respuesta {
    margin: auto 60px;
}
#googleMap {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width:90%;
    height:280px;
    border: 2px solid #666666; 
    border-radius: 6px;
}
#map {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width:90%;
    height:280px;
    border: 2px solid #666666; 
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.titular {
        background: #ffffff;
        font-size: 32px;
        color: #000;
        margin: 40px auto;
        text-align: center;
        width: 50%;
        padding:3px 10px 3px 10px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border: solid 1px #999999;
    }
```

maker.php is:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/xml'); 
echo '<markers>';
include ("conexion.php");
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from reg ORDER BY Id");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo "<marker id ='".$row['Id']."' lat='".$row['Lat']."' lng='".$row['Lng']."'>\n";
    echo "</marker>\n";
}
mysql_close($bd);
echo "</markers>\n";
?>
```

sql db is:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Servidor: localhost
-- Tiempo de generación: 10-08-2017 a las 19:40:25
-- Versión del servidor: 5.5.24-log
-- Versión de PHP: 5.4.3

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `marcadores`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `reg`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reg` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Lat` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '4.678402871749015',
  `Lng` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-74.09417855941774',
  `Pos` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `reg`
--

INSERT INTO `reg` (`Id`, `Lat`, `Lng`, `Pos`) VALUES
(1, '', '', ','),
(2, '4.678413564838687', '-74.09585225784303', '4.678413564838687,-74.09585225784303'),
(3, '4.679450793759737', '-74.09475791656496', '4.679450793759737,-74.09475791656496'),
(4, '4.68088366417397', '-74.09359920227052', '4.68088366417397,-74.09359920227052'),
(5, '4.678680892027193', '-74.09398544036867', '4.678680892027193,-74.09398544036867'),
(6, '4.677526037840907', '-74.09481156074526', '4.677526037840907,-74.09481156074526'),
(7, '4.676178705549802', '-74.09496176445009', '4.676178705549802,-74.09496176445009'),
(13, '4.680113764017544', '-74.09057367050173', '4.680113764017544,-74.09057367050173'),
(14, '4.682423461945482', '-74.09572351181032', '4.682423461945482,-74.09572351181032'),
(15, '4.680199308521195', '-74.098727585907', '4.680199308521195,-74.098727585907'),
(16, '4.677290789532407', '-74.10070169174196', '4.677290789532407,-74.10070169174196'),
(17, '4.673954532288243', '-74.09804094039919', '4.673954532288243,-74.09804094039919'),
(18, '4.672842443010129', '-74.09314859115602', '4.672842443010129,-74.09314859115602'),
(19, '4.676691975299647', '-74.09675348007204', '4.676691975299647,-74.09675348007204');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

this is a messagge of error from console

[error console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97Tjz.jpg)

Comment: `randomMarkers[i].marker` doesn't exist in at least one of the iterations. Try `console.log(randomMarkers[i]);` before that long to see what it contains.

Comment: The posted code doesn't exhibit that issue.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, including sample XML data (I suspect your data is bad...)

Comment: I added new information. Remember the first element there is´t fix. only de second.